# Changing imports that are always in scope in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, import, predef

In my Scala project I decided to change predefined imports. By default compiler puts:

```
import java.lang._
import scala._
import scala.Predef._
```

into scope, but that can be controlled with compiler flags. And that's what I am curious about - is there a settings, hidden configuration or a plugin that allows me to change, add or override what imports Intellij thinks are always present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 2.13 Scala officially supports [`Yimports`](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/6764) and IntelliJ respects that settings, which solves the issue.